# Add entity to the context without knowing the type

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Is it possible to add a POCO entity to the object context without knowing the type?

For example, here I'm adding an employee...

```
context.Employ.Attach(employer);
```

Is it possible to do something like this...

```
context.Attach(employer);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works...

```
context.Set(entity.GetType()).Attach(entity);
```

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to use the [`Set`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.set(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbContext.Set(System.Type)) property of your context. For example:

```
var entityType = employer.GetType();
context.Set(entityType).Attach(employer);
```

Comment: Looks like you beat me to it, by one minute.